# Unexpected end of input on ajax call

Tags: jquery, laravel

This is my code in Laravel project

```
$('.add').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = $(this).closest('form'),
    fd = form.serializeArray(),
    postId = $('input[name=post_id]').val();

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('.csrf-token').val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "posts/" + postId + "/comment",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: fd,
    success: function(res) {
      console.log(res)
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(res)
    }
  });
})
```

And this is my error-**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

Comment: Your code above does not give this error. You have an error elsewhere. Also you only need to delegate if the form is added after the page loads

Comment: And what is the server response for this request?